# A word for a text with meanings read in both directions?

Tags: single-word-requests

Not a palindrome at the word-order level, but one or more sentences that make perfectly good sense read in reverse order -- **but a different sense.**

Is there a term for this? (And if you don't know an English term, but do know a German or French one, that would help, too.)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @WeatherVane Clearly **not** a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @JamesRandom not "clearly" without an example.

Comment: @WeatherVane This question asks about reversed sentences with **different** meanings, the other is about reversed sentences with the **same** meaning. Seems clear to me.

Comment: Then why do you ask for an example?

Comment: @WeatherVane Because I can't think of one and I am curious. (Also, apparently it is what one is supposed to do here to be a Good Pedant)

Comment: Perhaps "Aspire to climb?" ... "Climb to a spire!" but the question needs an example, to be clear.

Comment: @WeatherVane: but it's not a letter-by-letter reversed sentence!

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy it is a word-by-word reversal as asked (with one split into two words).

Comment: It's not that clear what the author meant: word-by-word or letter-by-letter reversal. Let's wait for him to clarify it.

Comment: Table the repair.  Page the number.

Comment: Most texts that make sense when the word order is reversed convey a different sense in each case. For example, *Tom chases Jerry* is different from *Jerry chases Tom*. Likewise for *press any key*. Is there a particular sense you’re after? Also, how do you intend to use the word you’re seeking?

Comment: Clarify:  Do you mean "reverse order" word-by-word or letter-by-letter?

Comment: If word by word, do you mean a reversal of meaning: "I was happy, not sad" - > "sad, not happy was I"? Or is just a change enough: "here I am" - > "am I here?".

Comment: - "Most texts that make sense when the word order is reversed convey a different sense in each case." -- Exactly!  - "Also, how do you intend to use the word you’re seeking?" -- To refer to this thing.

Comment: I didn't give an example because the one that caused me to ask this question is a long one in a YouTube video. Do you want me to give the URL for the video?