# Is there a term for word sets that are like a palindrome but for whole set of words?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a term that are like a palindrome but for whole set of words and not just letters

Examples:

Set 1

- You do?
- Do you?

Set 2

- Venture Capital
- Capital Venture

Set 3

- List Item
- Item List

I've searched through the old questions and also googled quite a bit, but couldn't get a definitive answer. "Chiasmus" was a close one, but I'm not sure if it is the correct answer.

Also, thank you in advance since the comments form suggest that I avoid telling thanks in comments.

Comment: My French friend who regularly used to say "baggy dog" just couldn't understand why that didn't work.

Comment: Also asked before: [a word for a text with meanings read in both directions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493745/a-word-for-a-text-with-meanings-read-in-both-directions). The thing to do is to offer a bonus at the original, not ask exactly the same question again.

Comment: They remind me of the term used for a tool to pick, or manipulate, a lock. I call it a lock pick but the term of use is a *pick-lock*.